# QGIS converting to ASCII question

Tags: qgis, python, numpy

I am attempting to do some analysis on a raster file and I need to convert it to ASCII.  In QGIS, I used [Raster -> Conversion -> Translate] with the asc file format, and I suspect it is simply copying the file without converting anything. Are there any other suggestions on how to do the conversion?

Comment: Sure there is. I am running an analysis of a raster inside of numpy.. To do so I have to convert the rows and columns to strings so that the numpy text reader can read each row and column and perform the analysis.  This very much about GIS tool creation.

Comment: I used qgis to convert a raster file into an ascii file.  I think the problem is the translation didn't work.. As the files are encrypted and not in pure ascii format. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you think QGIS may be the root cause then can you edit your Question to describe how someone else can try to reproduce what you are seeing, please?

Comment: Please provide useful detail. For example, what is the source of the raster data (and its format). What version of QGIS? What do you see in the output with other tools (like GDAL)?

Comment: I am using QGIS 2.01.. The input raster is an ESRI format, I believe with the file extension of .ovr  and the process windows returns: Input file size is 4841, 6940
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.....

Comment: .ovr files are not (really) rasters, they are lower resolution overviews (aka pyramids) that are stored as separate files from the actual raster data.  What do you mean "ESRI format"? I can think of at least 4 "ESRI format" rasters (BIL,FLT,ASC & GRID)... What makes you think it is simply copying the file without converting anything?

Comment: Because an ascii file would be viewable in any standard text editor.. This is not.. I get an encryption error.

Comment: How are you specifying ASCII output? With a .asc file extension (or selecting "Files of type" [GDAL] Arc/Info ASCII GRID in the file picker) or by editing the `gdal_translate etc...` string at the bottom of the [Raster -> Conversion -> Translate] dialog? Just specifiying filename.asc won't output ASCII, it will output GeoTiff, you need to change `-of GTiff` to `-of AAIGrid`. Not very intuitive I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to specify ASCII output by using a *.asc file extension (or selecting "Files of type" [GDAL] Arc/Info ASCII GRID in the file picker) this won't work, the underlying `gdal_translate` call will output GeoTiff.

You need to edit the `gdal_translate etc...` string at the bottom of the [Raster -> Conversion -> Translate] dialog and change `-of GTiff` to `-of AAIGrid`. Not very intuitive I know. Perhaps worthy of an [enhancement/bug request](https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues)?

Edit: It should work according to this [tutorial page](http://wiki.tuflow.com/index.php?title=QGIS_Export_Raster_to_asc). However, selecting "Files of type" -> "[GDAL] Arc/Info ASCII GRID" in the file picker doesn't update the output format (-of) `gdal_translate` command string on QGIS 2.0.1 on my Ubuntu 12.04.4 PC.

Comment: I will just mention one final side note.  QGIS wouldn't allow me to change the next at the bottom of the translation window to -of AAIGrid...  I re-ran it directly in python and it worked fine..

Comment: @RyanBertram - did you click the Edit button (little pencil icon) to the right of the text in the QGIS Raster -> Conversion -> Translate tool? That will allow you to change the gdal_translate command text.

Comment: I did click on the 'pencil' icon.   Once it is toggled out of edit mode, it reverts back to the default output (GTiff).  I am filing a bug report.

Comment: @RyanBertram - I agree that's another bug. Workaround is to leave it in edit mode and just click Ok to run the conversion.

Comment: I tried that too.  That produces an additional dialogue box which informs the user of additional formats.

Comment: @RyanBertram - it worked for me.  The dialog box just presents what gdal_translate would print to a command prompt/terminal if it had been passed an incorrect command line.